# How do I add a child to an HTML Tag render element?

Tags: 7, theming

I need to reproduce this with render elements:

```
<div id="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Can't figure this one out!

Comment: I'm also totally frustrated by the fact that you cant nest render arrays of `'#type' => 'html_tag'`.  If you have to resort to `#markup`, `#prefix`, and `#suffix`, the whole point of having a render array is lost.  :-/

Comment: See also: https://api.drupal.org/comment/44333#comment-44333

Answer (score 2):

Please see the drupal API page on this.

A simple example could be:

```
// Shows how #prefix and #suffix can add markup into an array.
t('Using #prefix and #suffix') => array(
  '#markup' => '<div class="child"></div><div class="child"></div>',
  '#prefix' => '<div id="parent">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
),
```

or you could use children

```
t('using children demonstration') => array(
  '#markup' => '',
  'child1' => array('#markup' => '<div class="child"></div>'),
  'child2' => array('#markup' => '<div class="child"></div>'),
  '#prefix' => '<div id="parent">',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
),
```

Comment: I've looked through the API a lot looking for this.  What you showed me is still a bunch of markup... it's just enclosed in arrays.  Any thoughts on how to leave the markup out?  Or is this just the way it has to be done?  Thanks

Comment: If you want custom markup (i.e. not produced by drupal), then you will need to use either this approach or by editing a template file and placing it in there for instance